# Adding WebService Type into Custom Class Public Static Method

Tags: c#, class, asp.net-4.0

I seem to be having difficulty implementing a using for multiple namespaces of multiple services.  For example, I have the following Services as Namespaces:

`ServiceMemberIDSS`, `ServiceVenueIDSS`, `ServiceProspectIDSS`, etc. etc.

All of these Services have a property named, `AuthorizeHeader`

I would like to create a Method where the user can input the Namespace to use.

For example, to call `ServiceMemberIDSS`, I could include `using ServiceMemberIDSS;` and have this Method:

```
public static AuthorizeHeader Authorize()
{
    AuthorizeHeader _authHeader = new ServiceMemberIDSS.AuthorizeHeader();
    _authHeader.SetCredentials();
    return _authHeader;
}
```

And call it like:  `Authorize()`

But how can I change this so that either of these are possible:

```
Authorize.ServiceMemberIDSS();
Authorize.ServiceVenueIDSS();
Authorize.ServiceProspectIDSS();
```

or

```
Authorize(ServiceMemberIDSS);
Authorize(ServiceVenueIDSS);
Authorize(ServiceProspectIDSS);
```

How can either of these be done?  What do I need to do to the Authorize Method to make this work in either of those ways?

Comment: How about creating overloads for your `Authorize` method? I can't think of any other way to do it since you want to access a method within the different classes.

Comment: Overloads are fine, but how to do that with the namespaces??

Comment: My bad, I read the question wrongly and thought they were different *classes*. Well, apparently you can achieve what you want with reflection, but I'm unfamiliar with the topic. You could take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948518/how-can-i-pass-a-namespace-to-a-method . But frankly if it were just 3 namespaces I would **personally** take the easy way and add a `char`,`int` or `string` parameter to `Authorize`, then just decide on which namespace's method to call via conditions (`if-else`).

Comment: Ok, but I only know of 1 way to call namespaces, and that is with `using`, is there another way?

Comment: I don't think so. You're gonna have to add the `using` directive for all 3 namespaces, then call the different methods with their fully qualified names, but I might be wrong. Another question similar to yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258253/passing-a-namespace-into-a-function

Comment: Well, I need to pass this into a function like this:  `ServiceMemberIDSS.Member[] theMember = getMemberList(Authorize("ServiceMemberIDSS"), true, true, true, true, true);`  the first parameter is of type `AuthorizeHeader`, but that would mean that I would have to define the Method of that type, even if the return value is of that type, right?  If that is wrong, than what should be the type of the Method `Authorize`?

Comment: I think you should just define the `Authorize` method for each of your services/namespaces. Then you can just call `namespaceName.Authorize`, which would return the correct type. You can also shorten your namespace name with `using svcMember = ServiceMemberIDSS` then call the method with `svcMember.Authorize`.